# How to define a variable and insert a map function in ReactJS? 'function is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined

I am trying to add the accordian.js page into the app.js main page for compiling- I am having issues defining and writing out the function properly, how can I fix this?

My code is below:

App.js: How to add the accordian.js page components into this app.js page?

```js
import React from 'react'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'
import Tabs from './Components/Tabs'
import Accordian from './Components/Accordian'

const data = {
  categories: [
    {
      name: 'Faces',
      subCategories: [{ name: 'Yellow', symbols: ['X', 'O', 'P'] }],
    },
    {
      name: 'Flags',
      subCategories: [
        { name: 'Popular', symbols: ['X', 'O', 'P'] },
        { name: 'Unknown', symbols: ['L', 'Z', 'Q'] },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'Numbers',
      subCategories: [
        { name: 'Big', symbols: ['X', 'O', 'P'] },
        { name: 'Small', symbols: ['L', 'Z', 'Q'] },
        { name: 'Random', symbols: ['R', 'T', 'M'] },
      ],
    },
  ],
}

const App = () => {
  const [tabIndex, setTabIndex] = React.useState(0)
  const handleTabChange = (event, newTabIndex) => {
    setTabIndex(newTabIndex)
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Accordian heading={subCat.name}>
        {subCat.symbols.map((symbol) => (
          <div>{symbol}</div>
        ))}
      </Accordian>
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">Something</header>
        <Typography variant="h3">Placeholder_Symbols</Typography>
        <Tabs
          tab={tabIndex}
          tabs={data.categories}
          handleChange={handleTabChange}
        />
        <Accordian 
        heading={subCat.name}
        children={subCat.symbols}
         />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Accordian.js: I did create a map function for app.js, but I am not sure how 'subCat' needs to be defined, and if I am doing it correctly - I get errors thrown back at me.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import ExpansionPanel from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanel'
import ExpansionPanelSummary from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelSummary'
import ExpansionPanelDetails from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelDetails'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  heading: {
    fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(15),
    fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightRegular,
  },
}))

export default function SimpleExpansionPanel({ heading, children }) {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <ExpansionPanel>
        <ExpansionPanelSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel1a-content"
          id="panel1a-header"
        >
          <Typography className={classes.heading}>{heading}</Typography>
        </ExpansionPanelSummary>
        <ExpansionPanelDetails>{children}</ExpansionPanelDetails>
      </ExpansionPanel>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: You might want to add these components into a codesandbox project (as the import statements are providing an error in the embedded jsfiddle)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like a variable called `subCat` is in scope. Where is it supposed to come from? Is it supposed to be related to that `data` object above?

Comment: Hi! Maybe I should be using something else ? I was trying to use it to mean Subcategories. There is the data object and then also subcategories above 
- what my main goal is - is to add the components of accordian.js page, into the app.js page for compiling and executing. 

I am unsure of how to do so, I was thinking making use of a map function would be useful

Comment: You seem to have a nested data structure up there, and I don't quite know what the expected output should be. Do you want to map each category to an accordion component containing all of it's subcategories?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do! Can you help?

Comment: Seems like there's no relation between the App and the other SimpleExpansionPanel component. You will have to import it into the App file. But it already looks like you're using the Accordian component instead, so I don't really follow your intent.

Comment: Something like this would create an array of Accordian components, one for every subcategory:
        `categories.map(category => {
          const { name, subCategories } = category;
          return subCategories.map(subCat => {
            <Accordian 
              heading={subCat.name}
              children={subCat.symbols}
            />
          })
        })
        .flat()`

Comment: so - I am using material-ui for these components (it is already installed and activated in my react app) so that is why you are seeing things like the SimpleExpansionPanel. 

I have another page, called tab.js and that is set up. I need to add the accordian.js page into app.js now. 

Does that make more sense? 

How would I insert that map function into the app.js page and define it? That is where I have issues because I write it incorrectly.

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do with the Accordian, it looks like you'd want to do it inside the Tabs component. So your app component would just be: `<div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">Something</header>
        <Typography variant="h3">Placeholder_Symbols</Typography>
        <Tabs
          tab={tabIndex}
          tabs={data.categories}
          handleChange={handleTabChange}
        />
      </div>`

Then you could deal with the category data inside your Tabs component. Hard to write the whole app out in a SO comment though!

Comment: So the array I am mapping the accordian to - it should have 3 records (as there are 3 tabs). Eventually, I want to be able to add more than 3 tabs and 3 records but that later. 

How can I show you the tab.js page code? since comments are limited. That has a map function written in it. Again, just needing to implement accordian functions into the app.js page. The above code you have makes sense, but it just re uses the tab components, which I already have executed. Ideas? (thank you btw!)

Comment: The best way to share code would be putting it on GitHub or another source control repository, or maybe setting it up in an online workspace like stackblitz. It might be that you need to learn a bit more of the fundamentals of React and JS before doing this though. I recommend the Tyler McGinnis tutorials.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! :) I am still learning! How did you learn, or what resources did you find most useful if you don't mind me asking? Tyler is good, but he seems more for advanced devs.